# Join two pandas series of text with NA

Tags: python, pandas, join, series, na

I have two pandas Series with text which I want to join to obtain a Series with the joined text.

Both Series are based on the same index but one Series has fewer values which leads to NA values when joining.

Here is a toy example:

```py
import pandas as pd

s1 = pd.Series(['red', 'blue', 'green', 'black'], index=[1,2,3,4])
s2 = pd.Series(['large', 'small'], index=[1,3])

s1

    1      red
    2     blue
    3    green
    4    black
    dtype: object

s2

    1    large
    3    small
    dtype: object
```

Now I want to join the text of both Series with a separator to obtain following Series:

```
1      red,large
2           blue
3    green,small
4          black
```

And this is what I tried so far:

### 1.

```py
s1.str.cat(s2, sep=',')
```

```
1      red,large
2            NaN
3    green,small
4            NaN
dtype: object
```

**NaN values instead of value from first series**

### 2.

```py
s1.str.cat(s2, sep=',', na_rep='')
```

```
1      red,large
2          blue,
3    green,small
4         black,
dtype: object
```

**Trailing commas**

### 3.

```py
s1.str.cat(s2, sep=',', na_rep='').str.strip(',')
```

**This actually works, but it makes the code less understandable and I don't want to use any extra code to fix something that should be done correctly in the first place!**

### 4.

```py
pd.concat([s1,s2], axis=1).apply(','.join)
```

```py
TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, float found
```

### 5.

```py
pd.concat([s1,s2], axis=1).agg('|'.join, axis=1)
```

```py
TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, float found
```

**Does not work because of the NA values.**

So how can I get this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option

```
s1.append(s2).groupby(level=0).agg(','.join)
1      red,large
2           blue
3    green,small
4          black
dtype: object
```

Comment: Although I wanted to concatenate and merge the series "column-wise", I think your solution of appending rows with grouping and aggregation seems to be the most flexible way as it also allows for doing an outer join on `s1` and `s2` as well as extending it to more than 2 series with `pd.concat()`.
I think that just another flaw of pandas I have to live with.

Answer (score 0):

one work around could be to add the comma on `s2` before and then `cat` with `s1` and `na_rep=''` like:

```
print (s1.str.cat(',' + s2, na_rep=''))
1      red,large
2           blue
3    green,small
4          black
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for this concise solution. I just prefer YOBEN_S's solution as it is more flexible.